# How-to integrate gUnit ( ANTLR grammar testing ) in the NetBeans build cycle?

Tags: netbeans, ant, antlr

Background: I am using NetBeans 7.1 and ANTLR 3.4. I have integrated java code generation in the NetBeans build script using the following tutorial: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Integrating_ANTLR_without_learning_Ant. I want to use automated tests for testing grammars. I have read about gUnit on the ANTLR site. There are, supposedly, two modes: one 'direct' method and another method which generates jUnit code. I have worked with jUnit before.

Question(s):

- **What method is advisable? Direct or via jUnit? Or perhaps both?**
- **What should I do to integrate gUnit in the NetBeans build cycle?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preference is to use JUnit since then you can run the generated tests like any other JUnit test in NetBeans.

To get the JUnit classes you need to run the org.antlr.gunit.Interp class (in the Antlr JAR) as a Java program with the -o flag.  The result will be JUnit classes in the same dir as the gunit file.  Add the generated source to your project and compile/run.